# How to automate mail in IBM i system

Tags: python-3.x, ibm-midrange

I am currently working with IBMi. I want an automatic mail after completing few jobs for confirmation. How can I achieve this? I can run Python in my system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IBM has built in commands depending on your OS release.  They do require setting up the IBM SMTP server.  SNDSMTPEMM and SNDDST are the most used.

There are also third party products like my MAILTOOL software (www.bvstools.com/mailtool.html) that makes interacting with cloud servers like Office 365 and Gmail much easier than then IBM SMTP server.

PHP may also have some built in email capabilities as well as python.  But if you're looking for a command line interface after running jobs the first two are probably your best bet, depending on if you want to set up the IBM SMTP server or not.

Comment: One key thing is to get the logging right so that you can deal with any 'did it actually go out' type questions. Often works best if you direct external email via your organisation's main mail server (see CHGSMTPA command) and make sure all the traffic is logged to the QZMF journal. If you literally just want to send yourself an email confirmation within your own network, then you obviously don't need to do so much configuration work. I would, however, make sure no other application is already emailing from the box, before I changed anything!

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant by setting up the IBM SMTP server.  It's overly complicated for the most part.  :)  With MAILTOOL you can have all those settings at the system, user or command level so you're sure not to step on any toes.

Comment: I think the command is actually SNDSMTPEMM not SNDTCPEMM btw.